# Completely replace Fork with origin (github)

Tags: git, pull-request

Is there clever workflow to create a pull_request branch on a fork that is diverged from an upstream repo, so that the pull_request branch always perfectly matches the upstream "master"?

That is,

1) I have a fork which has diverged considerably from the parent remote.

2) I want to keep my fork (no sense in deleting it) but, I also want to cleanly issue pull requests which are minimally divergent from the original upstream repository.

Thus - is there a way to create a branch in my fork which is a perfect replica of another remote's master?

Comment: `git pull upstream master:upstream-master`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be modifying your local `master` branch, you should only be creating feature branches. If you keep your local `master` unmodified, then you can fetch the latest changes from the upstream repo:

```bash
git remote add upstream <url-for-upstream-repo>
git fetch upstream
```

Now your remote-tracking branch `upstream/master` is synced with the latest changes from `upstream`. Optionally, you can also update your local `master` if you want:

```
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
```

Now you can create feature branches off of `upstream/master`:

```
git checkout -b feature upstream/master
```

When you want to sync your feature branches with the latest changes from `upstream`, you can use `rebase`, as long as no one else is also working on the feature branch (otherwise you'll end up forcing them to re-sync with the changed history). `rebase` is actually ideal for this workflow, because you can usually use it to sync feature branches as frequently as you want without creating a messy history, because they don't create merge commits:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout feature
git rebase upstream/master
```

You could also `git merge upstream/master` instead of rebasing, but you'll leave behind a merge commit, so over time you'll create a more complicated history by merging instead of rebasing.

When you're ready to submit a pull-request, just push to your `origin` and make the request against the upstream `master`.

The original poster asks:

> [I]s there a way to create a branch in my fork which is a perfect replica of another remote's master?

As long as your local `master` hasn't diverged from `upstream/master` (which it shouldn't if you've been doing your work in feature branches instead of directly in `master`), then just push your local `master` to your `origin`:

```
git push origin master
```

Alternatively, you can use a refspec to push your remote-tracking branch `upstream/master` to your `origin/master`:

```
git push origin upstream/master:master
```

Comment: This is the best argument I ever heard for using branches for everything /

Answer (score 1):

To completely replace fork with origin:

```
git remote add upstream <upstream_repository_url>
git fetch upstream
git reset --hard upstream/master
```

Got this from [here](https://gist.github.com/glennblock/1974465)